# Android Thread problem

Tags: android, multithreading

I already know how to stop thread but my present scenario is somewhat different, I am listening for data from server in thread

```
while (connected) 
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    if(in.read(buffer) > 0)// waits on this line
    {
        //do something  
    }
 }
```

now the problem is that although I set connected = false; then also it not stopping because it waits  on in.read so , I also tried to Thread.interrupt but no luck

Comment: can you show what var 'connected' holds?

Comment: it holds true and when my app exits I set it to false

Comment: please make sure that you provide an [sscce](http://www.sscce.org/) compliant example...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified the code in following way

```
while (connected) 
{
   byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
   if(in.available()  > 0)// changed this line
   {
      in.read(buffer)
      //do something  
   }  
}
```

and it worked fine for me since in.available()  statement is non- blocking I suppose

Comment: You're essentially duplicating the work that `in.read(buffer)` is doing: i.e. spinning until you get some data. It's not necessarily bad, but it's not the optimal solution. Did you trying setting up a break point and catching the `InterrupetedException`?

Comment: yeah I already implemented that in mycode but that doesnt work

Answer (score 1):

You should probably switch to using a `SelectableChannel` approach to reading/writing to sockets where non-blocking I/O is used and you can manage multiple connections by listening for 'events'.  You then avoid being blocked in calls like `read()`.

This, unfortunetly, is a fundamentally different model to the one you are currently using, so the switch over won't be quick or easy, but it will be worth the effort.

Check out these resources:

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/channels/SocketChannel.html
http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.nio/NbClientSocket.html

Comment: Hi thanks for you reply but for this I have to change alot is there no simple solution

Comment: I don't think so, no.  Blocking calls will cause this type of problem.

Answer (score 1):

We need a little more info here:

1. How do you declare and modify `connected`?
2. Do you have a try-catch that is "eating" the `InterruptedException`?
3. How do you create the thread?
4. How are you starting the thread?
5. How do you (attempt to) terminate the thread?
6. Provide a [sscce](http://sscce.org/) compliant example which we can copy & paste, compile and see your exact problem.

In general your code should look like this:

```
while (connected) 
{
    try
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        if(in.read(buffer) > 0)// waits on this line
        {
            //do something  
        }
    }
    catch(InterruptedException ie)
    {
        // there are several ways which you can exit the loop:

        // 1. you can break
        // 2. set the connected flag to false

    }
}
```

Verify that you are actually catching the interrupt exception! If you're not catching it, then built a small [sscce](http://sscce.org/) compliant example in which you're only reproducing the specific issue (should be pretty easy to do).